# Сделать реверсную анимацию SVG иконки микрофона

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, анимация

При клике на элемент происходит анимация, но можно ли вернуть элемент в исходное состояние при повторном клике. (Сделать обратную анимацию)

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('div[role="button"]');
const micro = document.querySelectorAll('.micro');
btn.onclick = () => {
  micro.forEach((e) => {
    e.beginElement();
  });
}
```

```css
div[role="button"] {
  border: 0.0625rem solid;
  width: 68px;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div role="button">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="68" height="68" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <g>
    <rect id="top-part" x="9" y="3.5" width="6" height="12" rx="3" fill="#5A8CF6"/>
      <animate class="micro" xlink:href="#top-part" attributeName="height" from="12" to="6" dur="400ms" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" />
      <animate class="micro" id="drill" xlink:href="#top-part" attributeName="y" from="3.5" to="9" begin="indefinite" dur="400ms" fill="freeze" />
    </g>
    <g stroke="#5A8CF6" fill="none">
      <g>
        <circle id="baloon" cx="12" cy="12" r="6" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-dasharray="37.7" stroke-dashoffset="18.8"/>
        <animate xlink:href="#baloon" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="18.8" to="0" dur="300ms" begin="drill.end" fill="freeze"/>
      </g>
      <g>
        <rect id="leg" x="11" y="18" width="2" height="4" fill="#5A8CF6" stroke="none" transform-origin="top"/>
        <animate class="micro" xlink:href="#leg" attributeName="height" from="4" to="0" dur="400ms" begin="indefinite"  fill="freeze" />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Немного скорректировал SVG и добавил чуть-чуть JS. Правда, в погоне за минимальными изменениями, слегка изменилась анимация (не знаю, насколько это критично):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('div[role="button"]');
const micro = document.querySelectorAll('.micro');
btn.onclick = () => {
  micro.forEach((e) => {
    let sTemp = e.getAttribute('from');
    e.setAttribute('from', e.getAttribute('to'));
    e.setAttribute('to', sTemp);
    e.beginElement();
  });
}
```

```css
div[role="button"] {
  border: 0.0625rem solid;
  width: 68px;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div role="button">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="68" height="68" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <g>
      <rect id="top-part" x="9" y="3.5" width="6" height="12" rx="3" fill="#5A8CF6"/>
      <animate class="micro" xlink:href="#top-part" attributeName="height" from="6" to="12" dur="400ms" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze" />
      <animate class="micro" id="drill" xlink:href="#top-part" attributeName="y" from="9" to="3.5" begin="indefinite" dur="400ms" fill="freeze" />
    </g>
    <g stroke="#5A8CF6" fill="none">
      <g>
        <circle id="baloon" cx="12" cy="12" r="6" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-dasharray="37.7" stroke-dashoffset="18.8"/>
        <animate class="micro" xlink:href="#baloon" attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="18.8" dur="400ms" begin="indefinite" fill="freeze"/>
      </g>
      <g>
        <rect id="leg" x="11" y="18" width="2" height="4" fill="#5A8CF6" stroke="none" transform-origin="top"/>
        <animate class="micro" xlink:href="#leg" attributeName="height" from="0" to="4" dur="400ms" begin="indefinite"  fill="freeze" />
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Хотел уже ответ опубликовать, опередил, блин)

Answer (score 3):

- Зеленая кнопка имеет  `id="play"` Запуск анимации от радиокнопки к
  иконке микрофона Красная кнопка имеет  `id="stop"` Запуск анимации от
  иконки микрофона к радиокнопке
- Заменил прямоугольник на `<polyline>` с атрибутом
  `stroke-linecap="round"` что позволило убрать лишние анимации.
- Если анимация находится внутри тегов svg элементов, то не нужно
  писать `xlink:href` Эта переадресовка нужна, когда анимация находится
  **вне** анимируемых элементов.

```html
<style>
  div[role="button"] {
    border: 0.0625rem solid;
    width: 68px;
    font-size: 0;
  }
</style>
<div role="button">
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="68" height="68" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
    <polyline points="12,12 12,3.5" stroke="#5A8CF6" stroke-width="6" stroke-linecap="round">
      <animate attributeName="points" values="12,12 12,3.5;12,12 12,12" begin="stop.click" dur="0.4s" fill="freeze"/>
      <animate attributeName="points" values="12,12 12,12;12,12 12,3.5" begin="play.click" dur="0.4s" fill="freeze"/>  
    </polyline>
    <circle id="baloon" cx="12" cy="12" r="6" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="#5A8CF6" fill="none" stroke-dasharray="37.7" stroke-dashoffset="18.8">
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="18.8" to="0" begin="stop.click" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze"/>
      <animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" from="0" to="18.8" begin="play.click" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze"/>
    </circle>
    <rect id="leg" x="11" y="18" width="2" height="4" fill="#5A8CF6" stroke="none">
      <animate attributeName="height" from="4" to="0" begin="stop.click" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze"/>
      <animate attributeName="height" from="0" to="4" begin="play.click" dur="0.3s" fill="freeze"/>
    </rect> 
    <g id="play">
      <circle  cx="4" cy="20" r="3" fill="yellowgreen"/>
    </g>
    <g id="stop">
      <circle  cx="20" cy="20" r="3" fill="crimson"/>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Благодарю, как всегда помогло))

Comment: мне конечно понравилось решение но ответ не соответствует же вопросу

Comment: да это не наезд ... просто написано что при клике на элементе а в ответе при клике на два элемента получается ... это не наезд ..я тоже давно искал как можно сделать анимацию при клике два раза туда и обратно

Comment: @Alexandr_TT  извените за прошлую плохую беседу ... это не злость была

Comment: @Alexandr_TT мне эту площадку рекомендовал один человек но он говорил что он здесь был популярен ... но он ушёл отсюда отдав мне аккаунт

Comment: @UbuntuUser вот ссылка на топик, где искали решение https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/617723/28748

Comment: @Alexandr_TT там тоже по клику на кнопки ... не то ...и писал такой вопрос уже где то ... тоже ответа не было .. ладно ...ерунда ...наверно это не возможно

Comment: @Alexandr_TT чисто SVG - это круто, но JS наше всё)) А то повадились - анимировать через CSS, а оформлять с помощью JS)))