# Как сделать, чтобы SVG анимация продолжалась с того же места, где и закончилась

Tags: javascript, svg, css-animation, svg-animation, smil

Есть анимация вращения палки по кругу.
Она запускается по наведению мыши и прекращает вращаться по убиранию мыши с изображения.
Мне надо сделать так, что бы при повторном наведении анимация продолжалась с того же места где и закончилась при прекращении.

По идее за это должна отвечать `accumulate="sum"` но что-то не помогает.

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="170px" height="170px" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" version="1.1">
 <circle r="22" fill="orange" />
 <line x1="0" y1="-40" x2="0" y2="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="6" />
<animateTransform attributeName="transform" begin="svg1.mouseenter" end="svg1.mouseleave" type="rotate"
                repeatCount="indefinite" restart="never  " dur="10s" from="0" to="360" accumulate="sum" fill="freeze" /> 
</svg>
```

PS: Надо сделать без JavaScript, либо указать что это невозможно без него.

Answer (score 6):

У SVG нет переменных, в которых можно было бы хранить количество кликов. Допустим первый клик запуск анимации, второй клик пауза. И изменения после прохождения части анимации тоже хранить негде.

Поэтому решение задачи по остановке и запуске анимации с того же места можно решить только с помощью JS

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg1"  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="170px" height="170px" viewBox="-50 -50 100 120" version="1.1" style="border: 1px solid;">
 <circle r="22" fill="orange" /> 
 <circle r="40" fill="none" stroke="purple" stroke-dasharray="1.93 19" stroke-dashoffset="1.19" stroke-width="8" />
 
 <line x1="0" y1="-40" x2="0" y2="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="6" >
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.click" repeatCount="indefinite"  dur="10s" from="0 0 0" to="360 0 0"  restart="whenNotActive" /> 
  </line>
 <g id="gO1" onclick='start()'>
        <circle cx="-30" cy="50"  r="6" fill="green" stroke="black" />
        <text x="-42" y="67" font-size="12" fill="green">Start</text>
      </g>
      <g  onclick='pause()'>
        <circle cx="30" cy="50"  r="6" fill="red" stroke="black" />
        <text x="20" y="67" font-size="12" fill="red">Stop</text>
      </g>
    </g>
</svg>

<script>
 var flag = 0,
    svg = document.querySelector('svg'),
    $svg = $(svg);

// Необходимо поймать второй клик (если на первом удалить атрибуты, анимация не начнётся), потом подменяем функцию на вызов по "разморозке" анимации
var start = function(){
  if(flag === 1){
    // Убираем у animateTransform триггер, чтобы не сбрасывалась анимация на ноль
    $svg.find('animateTransform').removeAttr('begin');
    
    start = function() {
      svg.unpauseAnimations()
    };
     start();
  }
  flag++;
}
var pause = function(){
  svg.pauseAnimations();
}
   </script>
```

**Вариант с наведением на кнопки**

Используется событие `onmouseover`

`<g id="gO1" onmouseover='start()'>`
`<g id="stop"  onmouseover='pause()'>`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg1"  version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="170px" height="170px" viewBox="-50 -50 100 120" version="1.1" style="border: 1px solid;">
 <circle r="22" fill="orange" /> 
 <circle r="40" fill="none" stroke="purple" stroke-dasharray="1.93 19" stroke-dashoffset="1.19" stroke-width="8" />
 
 <line x1="0" y1="-40" x2="0" y2="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="6" >
 <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="svg1.mouseover" repeatCount="indefinite"  dur="10s" from="0 0 0" to="360 0 0"  restart="whenNotActive" /> 
  </line>
 <g id="start" onmouseover='start()'>
        <circle cx="-30" cy="50"  r="6" fill="green" stroke="black" />
        <text x="-42" y="67" font-size="12" fill="green">Start</text>
      </g>
      <g id="stop"  onmouseover='pause()'>
        <circle cx="30" cy="50"  r="6" fill="red" stroke="black" />
        <text x="20" y="67" font-size="12" fill="red">Stop</text>
      </g>
    </g>
</svg>

<script>
 var flag = 0,
    svg = document.querySelector('svg'),
    $svg = $(svg);

// Необходимо поймать второй клик (если на первом удалить атрибуты, анимация не начнётся), потом подменяем функцию на вызов по "разморозке" анимации
var start = function(){
  if(flag === 1){
    // Убираем у animateTransform триггер, чтобы не сбрасывалась анимация на ноль
    $svg.find('animateTransform').removeAttr('begin');
    
    start = function() {
      svg.unpauseAnimations()
    };
     start();
  }
  flag++;
}
var pause = function(){
  svg.pauseAnimations();
}
   </script>
```

Скрипт был взят из этого [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/639911/28748)

Comment: Да, про то что переменных нет, это понятно. Но зачем тогда вообще этот `fill="freeze"` есть, если не позволяет с того же места продолжить анимацию? Какой смысл её ступорить, если продолжить с этого же места нельзя. Опять же есть свойства `accumulate="sum"` , `additive="sum"` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/accumulate , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/additive. Я так понимаю что они на что-то подобное что нужно мне и направлены...

Comment: Думаю что может быть решение основанное на `accumulate="sum"` , `additive="sum"`, `fill="freeze"` , ну или нужно понимание что эти свойства о другом. Хорошо бы вопрос о том что это за свойства и как они работают. Постараюсь сегодня сделать в виде вопроса. И тут засчитаю ответ, только как на 100% пойму что решения на чистом SVG нет. Лайк, конечно ставлю, ответ - полезный.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин fill="freeze" нужно, чтобы заморозить анимацию в конце. Иначе, всё бы тут же исчезало - по умолчанию `fill="remove"`    `accumulate="sum"` , `additive="sum"`, служат для накапливания результатов нескольких анимаций, а не вычитания. Короче, Дима это довольно сложный вопрос, но чистого решения SVG, точно нет!

Comment: Оформил в виде отдельного вопроса - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1106193/Как-работают-и-зачем-нужны-svg-свойства-accumulate-sum-additive-sum-fill

Comment: Вот, накапливания. Это и надо. Один раз провёл анимацию, заморозил, накопил, и далее следующая. Возможно проблема в begin, который начинает с первой точки... Я не спорю. Рассуждаю и пытаюсь понять логику. А поняв логику станет ясно что можно и как и что нельзя и почему.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин с помощью begin можно организовать цепочку анимаций, но только по логике - вторая анимация начнется, когда полностью закончится первая анимация или ещё можно добавить условие `begin="an1.end"` или `begin ="an1.end -1s"`  Разные условия можно написать, но они жестко определены заранее, однозначные В svg нигде не запоминается, тот момент, когда пользователь уведет мышку Пожтому снова начать анимацию с того же места, просто невозможно. Эту задачу решает только JS

Comment: Надо писать ишью с feature request для SVG animate

Comment: Но вопрос что такое accumulate="sum" всёже остаётся

Comment: Теперь верю что `begin` на это не влияет, по причине что ты объяснил

Comment: У себя сделаю как ты предложил, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Получилось найти решение! Правда не через SMIL. Ответ написал.

Answer (score 5):

Получилось решить задачу средстваами чистого CSS

```css
#svg1:hover {
  animation-play-state: running;
}

#svg1 {
  animation-duration: 8s;
  animation-name: rot1;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes rot1 {
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="170px" height="170px" viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" version="1.1">
 <circle r="22" fill="orange" />
 <line x1="0" y1="-40" x2="0" y2="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="6" />
</svg>
```

Идея ответа взята [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150865/beginning-and-pausing-svg-animations-on-hover).

Comment: да согласен если задача просто крутить но если что то сложнее, к примеру изменение (morph) шейпа то css не умеет такое