# Как работают и зачем нужны SVG свойства accumulate="sum" , additive="sum", fill="freeze"?

Tags: svg, svg-animation, smil

Разбираясь с этим вопросом [Как сделать что бы SVG анимация продолжалась с того же места где и закончилась](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1105812/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D1%8B-svg-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B6%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C)

Ещё надеюсь что найдётся решение, поэтому возникает вопрос как работают аттрибуты SVG анимации?

- `accumulate="sum"`
- `additive="sum"`
- `fill="freeze"`

В интернете мало что по ним получилось найти, а то что нашёл не очень понятно.

Ссылки по вышеуказанным атрибутам:

- `accumulate` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/accumulate
- `additive` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/additive
- `fill="freeze"` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/fill

Answer (score 1):

Ответ на эти вопросы есть в этой [статье](https://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/) . Очень добротная статья подробно описывающая многие аспекты `SMIL` анимации на английском языке.

Ответ будет без примеров, которые можно посмотреть в статье выше.

- `additive="sum"` При выставленном `sum` точки from и to будут считаться не абсолютно а прибавлены к изначальному значению анимационного параметра.
- `accumulate="sum"` Относится к повторяющейся анимации с `repeatCount`. В случае `sum` каждый следующий виток цикла будет начинаться не с начального значения а с того значения на котором остановились на предыдущем витке цикла.
- `fill="freeze"` означает что после окончания анимации анимация замрёт на точке её окончания, а не вернётся в начало.